# ShakeDetector is not working in Fragment, how can I do

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, shake

My shake detector is not working in fragment. But worked in activity. what is the reason for this, what should i do.How can ı solve.

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    presenter.takeView(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: " + this);
    presenter.initListener();
    initUI();

    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    ShakeDetector sd = new ShakeDetector(this);
    sd.start(sensorManager);

}
```

My shake detectror code;

```
@Override
public void hearShake() {
          int position= listDataAdapter.getPosition();
          listDataAdapter.removeItem(position);
          UserItemPojo item = listDataAdapter.removeItem(position);
          if (item != null)
              sub_main_presenter.doLike(item);
          presenter.isEmpty();

          if (userList.isEmpty())
              homePresenter.stopPlayer();

          Toast.makeText(getContext(),"shakeDetector is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "is not working". How is it not working?

Comment: working in an activity but not working in fragment actually the application is closing